# Eigenvectors of the angular momentum operator $S_x$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, eigenvalue, normalization

For a spin of $\frac{1}{2}$ the angular momentum operator can be written as $\vec{S} = \frac{\hbar}{2} \vec{\sigma}$ in matrix form. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $S_x$ where
$\sigma_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$

**Attempt:**

- ***Finding the eigenvalues:***

$|S_x - \lambda I|=det\begin{bmatrix} -\lambda & \hbar/2 \\ \hbar/2 & -\lambda\\\end{bmatrix} = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda = \pm\hbar/2$

As far as I know that is correct so far.

- ***Finding the eigenvectors:***

Using $\lambda = -\hbar/2$ first: (I don't get a correct answer for this one, but I do for the other eigenvalue)

$\begin{bmatrix} \hbar/2 &\hbar/2 \\ \hbar/2 & \hbar/2\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \alpha  \\ \beta \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

$\Rightarrow (\hbar/2)\alpha + (\hbar/2)\beta = 0$

$\Rightarrow (\hbar/2)\alpha + (\hbar/2)\beta = 0$

Therefore the corresponding eigenvector is $c  \begin{bmatrix} -1  \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $ where $c$ is some constant. I know that the answer should be $c\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} $ where after normalisation $c$ is found to be $1/\sqrt{2}$.

**Where have I gone wrong? The eigenvalues are correct so it can't be that.**

Comment: An eigenvector $(a,b)$ represents a state that has a probability of $|a|^2$ being spin up, and a probability of $|b|^2$ being spin down. For the probabilities to sum to one, the eigenvector must be normalized.

Comment: So I need to normalise my eigenvector. Aha... I see. That accounts for the $1/\sqrt{2}$. Great!

Comment: @leongz I get that now, but do you mind explaining the updated question?

Comment: @PPG: Well $(-1,-1)$ is not a solution of your equation, but $(1,-1)$ is...

Comment: @Adam Do you mind explaining/showing me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @PPG: Well (−1,−1) is not a solution of your equation, but (1,−1) is... –  Adam

What he said was:

- ***Finding the eigenvectors***

*You did right... but:*
$$(\hbar/2)\alpha+(\hbar/2)\beta=0\implies\alpha+\beta=0\implies\beta=-\alpha $$
Then, the corresponding eigenvector is: $ c\left[\begin{array}{c}
      1 \\
      -1
    \end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Oh dear, my maths teacher never explained eigenvectors properly. I thought you have to find them a different way. That looks much easier (and correct) and I now feel stupid -_-

Comment: You're welcome!. Lol!. Don't fell bad! Just remember that for you next eigenvalue/eigenvector problem :P.

Comment: However, could I ask what would have happened if I had done a = -b. That would lead to c(-1 1) and isn't that a completely different answer?

Comment: Mmmm... No because $(1,-1) \wedge (-1,1) \in <\{(1,-1)\}>$ and, in quantum mechanics you are looking for any vector belonging to that space, because they differ in a "global" complex phase ($(1,-1)=-1(-1,1)=e^{i\pi}(-1,1)$). Am I making myself clear?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood any of that. Are you saying that it is essentially the same answer, or that I cannot do $\alpha = -\beta$?

Comment: Yes, *physically* it's the same answer. That it's called the *Gauge symmetry* [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state).

Comment: Aha, I see now. My mistake was that I did both $\alpha = -\beta$ ***AND*** $\beta = -\alpha$. I think you see how I got $c(-1 , -1)$ from that... Thanks!

Comment: No problem! You're welcome.

Comment: @Wikitys: That's not Gauge symmetry yet. It's just that quantum mechanics does not care about the global phase of the wave function. (Gauge symmetry would imply that the phase changes as a function of the position, which would clearly make no sense here.)

Comment: @Adam: Ok. But, if we call this *Global phase invariance* a kind of *Global phase symmetry*. Isn't a particular case of the *Gauge symmetry*?. I didn't read this, I'm just asking.

Comment: @Wikitys: I would not say so, because this invariance is true for every quantum system, and has nothing to do with a symmetry of the Hamiltonian (it is an invariance of the wave-function only). On the other hand a symmetry of the Hamiltonian implies symmetries on the eigen-function, but that does not mean that any linear combination of these eigen-functions will have the symmetry. For example, if the Hamiltonian is invariant under $\hat x\to -\hat x$, the eigenfunction will be odd or even in $x$ ($\psi_o(-x)=-\psi_o(x)$ and $\psi_e(-x)=\psi_e(x)$), but the very physical wavefunction ...

Comment: @Wikitys: ... $\phi(x)=\phi_o(x)+\phi_e(x)$ is neither odd nor even.

Comment: @Adam: I understand your point. I thought that the Hamiltonian was invariant under transformation $g \in U(1)$, i.e.: a $U(1)$ gauge symmetry. I didn't thought only in the eigenstates of $H$.OK, Thanks for help me to make up my mind.

Comment: @Wikitys: Sure, you're welcome :-)